# Fancybox will not open

Tags: jquery, fancybox, circular-content-carousel

I'm using a content carousel (from codrops) and each item opens more info with Fancybox. The problem is, Fancybox will not open. I'm thinking there may be a jquery conflict as I am using jquery.migrate in order for the carousel to work.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="#historyslide1" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="historygaller"><img src="img/historyslider/1900.jpg" class="img-responsive">
<h3>1900</h3>
<p>Benjamin Bones.... </p>
<span class="historyplus">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```

Should Open:

```
<div id="history-slide1"> class="historyslider">text text</div >
```

JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({

        closeBtn: false,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade',
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        maxWidth: 800,
        loop: false
    });
});
```

Site is here: http://smmcnyc.com/work/bnc/history.html

Comment: data-fancybox-group="historygallery" and the div in id="history-slide1" is closed. Fancybox would open when jquery 1.10 was being used

Comment: Is this `<div id="history-slide1"> class="historyslider">text text</div >` a typo or your actual code? if the second, there is a syntax error (an extra closing `>` between the `id` and the *class*)

Comment: also, watch for js errors in your console. Other scripts error may prevent fancybox from working

Answer (score 0):

fixed using

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.min.js"></script>   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-git.min.js"></script>
```

and updating fancybox version